# jquery permanently alter html

Tags: php, jquery

How would I go about permanently add a class to a html element using jQuery.

I am planning on building a image gallery that is sorted into types/categories using the [jQuery sorting plugin](http://www.jscodes.com/jquery-sorting-product-pictures/). I want to add a dropdown box below each image that allows the user to change the type (add/remove class) which permanently changes the HTML for next load. How would I go about this?

EDIT: Ok so from what I can put together I should use this approach:

1. Jquery add/removes class.
2. Send full HTML of source via AJAX request.
3. PHP writes full HTML to file or is there a way to replace only a particular part of a file in PHP?

Comment: Is that change available to all user? Or are each user independent?

Comment: Too broad in scope. You're basically asking how to write a mini CMS! (sort of)

Comment: Nope not a CMS, just one page that sorts images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to know the distinction between Client side scripting and Server side programming.

The server will return you a set of html on each response which is generated by the server side php in your case.

If you want to modify a class on a certain element, and you want this change to survive the next generated server side php response, you need to somehow inform the server of your change.

There are several options to send data from the client side to the server side.

1. Store the value in a hiddenfield
2. Make an ajax request and store the value somewhere on the server so it is aware of this change at the request.
3. Add it to the querystring of the url being requested.

Comment: Ok I understand the AJAX process and that this needs to be done in PHP but is there any way to physically change the file by adding the class name?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to change the type using a dropdown, so when you apply a filter the results will change? (I got this from looking at at the demo site)

Comment: Yes that's correct, although instead of saving this in a cookie or getting a database involved, I was wondering how I could go about actually modify the HTML permanently, as simple as add/remove a class.

Comment: Well the answer to that is quite simple, you can't. Every time the user will refresh the page, the changes will be lost. Because the server is not aware of the change. What you should do is an ajax post to a method on the server with an identifier of the item and the identifier of the selected type. In this method you store these values to a database and at every refresh you assign each item the type that is in your database. This is quite standard practice for webapplications these days.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [jQuery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) functionality to send back edited HTML to the server to be stored in your database after the user has made their changes.

You can then build up the relevant parts of your page from your database on the next load.

```
$('#mySelectBox').change(function(){
$.ajax({
  url: "updateHtml.php",
  data: $('#myEditedHtmlContainer').html(),
  success: function(){
    // do something on success
  }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to store user decision in cookie. The during very page load, you'll need to check for the appropriate value in the cookie and based on it apply the CSS.

Comment: Only an OK solution if the user who applied the classes is the only one who needs to see them.